Spring controller unit test with profiles, mongodb and test containers
I'm trying to write complex unit tests for my Spring MVC application, but I've hit a roadblock. While the application works as expected when I start it from the main development class with launched docker mongo container but Spring seems unable to load even a simple unit test.
My setup is:

JWT implementation as a security
Mongo DB docker's container, separate for tests and development
I use profiles in the main app class, but to pick profile setup I use @ConditionalOnProperty in proper beans

This is my code snippets:
Spring boot main application class:
package com.example.fluere;
import com.example.fluere.bootloader.MongoService;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

@Profile({"dev", "test"})
@EnableMongoRepositories
@SpringBootApplication
public class FluereApplicationDev {
public static void main(String\[\] args) {
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(FluereApplicationDev.class, args);
MongoService mongoService = context.getBean(MongoService.class);
mongoService.performConnectivityCheck();
}
}

Spring test main class:
package com.example.fluere;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;

@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = FluereApplicationDev.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class FluereApplicationTest {
@Test
void ContextLoad() {
}
}

controller unit test class:
package com.example.fluere.expense.controller;

import com.example.fluere.FluereApplicationTest;
import com.example.fluere.budget.model.BudgetIdWrapper;
import com.example.fluere.currencyapi.model.MKTCurrency;
import com.example.fluere.expense.controller.user.ExpenseController;
import com.example.fluere.expense.model.Expense;
import com.example.fluere.expense.model.ExpenseDetails;
import com.example.fluere.expense.model.ExpenseIdWrapper;
import com.example.fluere.expense.model.ExpenseType;
import com.example.fluere.expense.service.user.DefaultExpenseService;
import com.example.fluere.userentity.model.UserIdWrapper;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.testcontainers.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.TreeMap;

@ActiveProfiles("test")
@WebMvcTest(ExpenseController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = FluereApplicationTest.class)
@WithMockUser(username = "admin", password = "colombo")
public class ExpenseUserControllerTest {
private static final ExpenseIdWrapper EXPENSE_ID = ExpenseIdWrapper.newFromString(
"85a227c5-d438-4767-8856-a8ff0afb3071");
private static final BudgetIdWrapper BUDGET_ID = BudgetIdWrapper.newFromString(
"cf63fc6f-2904-4d25-b806-557ae960b165");
private static final UserIdWrapper USER_ID = UserIdWrapper.newFromString("d58e3dd1-096f-42f9-b975-9c9b2adee788");
private static final String BASE_EXPENSE_CONTROLLER_PATH = "/api/expenses";
private static final LocalDateTime EXPENSE_DATE = LocalDateTime.of(1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
private static final ExpenseDetails EXPENSE_DETAILS = ExpenseDetails.newOf(
"Apple", BigDecimal.ONE, MKTCurrency.PLN, new TreeMap\<\>(), ExpenseType.ACCOMMODATION, "");
private static final Expense ENTITY = Expense.newOf(EXPENSE_ID, BUDGET_ID, USER_ID, EXPENSE_DETAILS);
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;
@Autowired
private ExpenseController controller;
@MockBean
private DefaultExpenseService service;
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Test
    void someTest() {
    
    }
}

Here's my app config properties:
application.yml:
spring:
 profiles:
  active: dev
---
admin:
 key:
  value: "${ADMIN_KEY_VALUE}"
---

application-dev:
dev:
  username: "dev"
  password: "dev"
---
logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        data:
          mongodb:
            core:
              MongoTemplate: DEBUG
---
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: flueredb
      port: 27017
      host: "localhost"
      username: admin
      password: admin
      authentication-database: admin
---
#logging:
#  level:
#    ROOT: DEBUG
---
app:
  property:
    service:
      bootloader-info: true
      security-setup: "demo"
      currency-hardcoded: true

application-test.yml:
test:
  #  datasource:
  username: "test"
  password: "test"
---
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: flueredb_test
      port: 27018
      host: "localhost"
      username: test
      password: test
      authentication-database: admin
---
app:
  property:
    service:
      bootloader-info: true
      security-setup: "demo"
      currency-hardcoded: true

I'm heading towards using TestContainers library for tests, right now I have separate container only to check if tests are loaded by Spring.
I want to write junit tests for all controllers, services and repository layers with mocked beans. Only for repository layer I decided to use TestContainers library.
First of all I wrote a test and created simple class only to check if Spring is able to find it. I noticed that when I commented ExpenseController bean spring seems to load test class. Which is strange to me because I read @WebMvcTest doesn't load the whole app context. It should load only the controller.
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@WebMvcTest(ExpenseController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = FluereApplicationTest.class)
@WithMockUser(username = "admin", password = "colombo")
public class ExpenseControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

//    @Autowired
//    private ExpenseController controller;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    
    @MockBean
    private DefaultExpenseService service;
    
    @Test
    void someTest() {
    }

}

Once it's uncommented I got this:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.fluere.expense.ExpenseControllerTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'controller': No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.fluere.expense.controller.user.ExpenseController' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I've tried various Spring annotations, but nothing has helped so far.
